# Lipschutz Ex. 4.77

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given matrix $B=\begin{bmatrix}{1}&{0}\\{26}&{27}\end{bmatrix}$. Find a matrix $A$ such as $A^3=B$.

I've been trying to solve this one for quite some time but I cannot think of a solution, nor can I find something similar so I can get an idea.

My initial thought process was to assume a matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}{a}&{b}\\{c}&{d}\end{bmatrix}$ so I could get a system of equations but I feel like there should be an easier solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $b=0$, compute $A^2$ (which is easy) and then $A^3$

Comment: I agree with @RobertZ you just can't keep using Algebra try to observe the pattern of the element $a_{12}$ will be always zero

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\x&3\end{smallmatrix}\right]^3=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\13x&27\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Answer (score 0):

$$X^n = PD^nP^{-1}$$
$$\pmatrix{1&&0\\26&&27}^n = \pmatrix{-1&&0\\1&&1}\pmatrix{1&&0\\0&&27}^n\pmatrix{1&&0\\-1&&-1}\frac1{-1}$$
$\lambda_1 = 1\to I_{g1} = \pmatrix{-1\\1}$ and $\lambda_2 = 27\to I_{g2} = \pmatrix{0\\1}$

$$\begin{align*}
\pmatrix{1&&0\\26&&27}^{\frac13} 
&=\pmatrix{-1&&0\\1&&1}\pmatrix{1&&0\\0&&27}^{\frac13}\pmatrix{1&&0\\-1&&-1}\frac1{-1}\\
& = \pmatrix{-1&&0\\1&&1}\pmatrix{1&&0\\0&&3}\pmatrix{-1&&0\\1&&1}\\
& = \pmatrix{-1&&0\\1&&3}\pmatrix{-1&&0\\1&&1}\\
& = \pmatrix{1&&0\\2&&3}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I'm uncertain if $X^n = PD^{n}P^{-1}$ works for fractional values of $n$